# Javascript - Using regex to process all matched groups in-place

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Here is an example of my problem:

For this string: *"Hello my name is {{Jaques}} and I am from {{France}}."*

I want it to output: *"Hello my name is JAQUES and I am from FRANCE."*

I assumed I could do this by using a match and replace with the regEx {{(.*?)}}, but I am having a little difficult getting it to give me the group data so that I can do the replace.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a callback function and use [toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) for the capturing group.

The `{{` and `}}` will be matched and not returned. The group will be returned with the uppercase value of group 1.

```js
let str = "Hello my name is {{Jaques}} and I am from {{France}}.";
let res = str.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function(_, g1) {
  return g1.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: That's perfect. I must have overlooked that whilst reading the documentation. I will accept your answer as soon as I am allowed to. Thank you.